# Angular 6 service only library

Tags: angular

I would like to have an Angular 6 library that only publishes a singleton service.

Here is a simple Angular library that only contains this service:

test54-library/src/lib/test54-library.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Test54LibraryService {
  constructor() { }
  testCall() {
    console.log('this is a testcall');
  }
}
```

test54-library/src/public_api.ts

```
export * from './lib/test54-library.service';
```

Do I have to have a module like this in this library that references this service in a providers entry? Why is a module needed in this usecase?

```
@NgModule()
export class Test54Module {
  static forRoot():ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModuleTest54Module,
      providers: [
        Test54LibraryService
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There are suggestions to close this question. Please elaborate why

Comment: You don't need a module, but someone has to provide the service. So either the library consumer imports a module that does it or provides the service on their own. A module is both more idiomatic in Angular and makes it easy to extend the library in the future; if you do ever need to add something, things get messy for library consumers otherwise.

Comment: thank you @IngoBürk. Do you think there is a better way of sharing services and factories?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to provide the service again. the `providedIn: 'root'` does the work for you.

Please refer: [singleton-services](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer- I still wonder- is there a better way to share factory and service code?

Comment: Guess there is a misunderstanding as the TO would like to have a service, which he can share between different web applications and not inside only one. So the link doesn't help.

Comment: Sharing a service between web applications cannot be done using providers, we should be relying upon HTTP protocol for that.